# Deploy Smart Contract to Mainnet using Truffle

Tags: truffle, gas-limit

I was able to deploy the contract successfully to Kovan with gas limit 350000.

When i set the gas in truffle.js to 500000 for deployment to Mainnet, i get the below error:
Error: Transaction cost exceeds current gas limit. Limit: 5000, got: 500000. Try decreasing supplied gas.

So i decrease the gas to 5000, i got the error below:
Error: Transaction gas is too low. There is not enough gas to cover minimal cost of the transaction (minimal: 498172, got: 5000).

it just won't deploy the contract, how can the Limit is so much lesser than minimal? how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try deploying it with web3.js directly: add `"web3": "1.0.0-beta.34"` to your `package.json`, rerun `npm install`, and keep in mind that since Truffle still relies on web3.js v0.x, the API is slightly (or very) different. I wrote an answer to a similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/56929/16043). You can follow the exact procedure described in that answer.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your node it is not fully synced or it is not syncing to mainnet. Currently the block gas limit is 8M.

Answer (score 1):

1.Use truffle v5
2.Use MNEMONIC phrase and fund the account.

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

const hd = new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC);
console.log('your address ', hd.addresses[0])
process.exit(1)
```

2.Here is truffle.js config below

```
const {MNEMONIC, NETWORK} = process.env;
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider')
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    mnemonic: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://${NETWORK}.infura.io`),
      network_id: '*',
      gas: 6500000,           // Default gas to send per transaction
      gasPrice: 1000000000,  // 10 gwei (default: 20 gwei)
      confirmations: 0,       // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
      timeoutBlocks: 200,     // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: false        // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true, // Default: false
          runs: 200     // Default: 200
        },
      }
    }
  }
};
```

3. Run deployment
   `MNEMONIC='YOUR SEED' NETWORK=kovan npx truffle migrate --reset --network mnemonic`

you can change `kovan` to `mainnet` or `rinkeby` or `ropsten`